# Is CefSharp multithreaded?

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am using CEFSharp in a C# application and I need to load multiple urls at a time in at least 10 WebView. However it does not work as multithreaded. Is there a way to run it in multithreaded otherwise do I have to rebuild from source with specific compile options ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It works, although it is not good enough.
Based on CefSharp.Example, changes:
1) an applicaton (or an process) calls only Once ExamplePresenter.Init() or CEF.Initialize(settings);
2) only when application (or process) will exit, do 
"CEF.Shutdown(); System.Environment.Exit(0);"